# Different way of calling methods in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to know what is the difference between:

```
onPressed: method

onPressed: method()

onPressed: () => method()
```

in `onPressed` parameter of a `RaisedButton` in Flutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually 4 ways of putting it.

1. *Property*: Button is clickable and method gets triggered on clicking it

   ```
    onPressed: () => method()
   ```
2. *Property*: Button is clickable and method gets triggered on clicking it

   ```
   onPressed: method
   ```
3. *Property*: Button is clickable but method never gets triggered

   ```
   onPressed: () => method
   ```
4. *Property*: Button is **NOT** clickable and method gets triggered as soon as this widget builds

   ```
   onPressed: method()
   ```

---

Now you can see 1 and 2 are doing the same job, the only difference is, in # 1, there is anonymous method/function which calls this method.

Answer (score 0):

1. `onPressed: myCall` This will trigger the method myCall when the onPressed attribute action has happened.
2. `onPressed: myCall()` This is an invocation of the method
3. `onPressed: ()=>mycall()` This creates an anonymous function which class the method mycall()
4. The onPressed parameter of a RaisedButton is simply a field similar to any other object. This field, instead of being a primitive (I.E. a Boolean or an Integer), is a function. As you may have noticed, it is a required field for the RaisedButton. Meaning, you cannot create an instance of a RaisedButton without supplying a value for the onPressed attribute. Below is a code snippet for the constructor of RaisedButton:

   ```
    class RaisedButton extends MaterialButton {
    /// Create a filled button.
    ///
    /// The [elevation], [highlightElevation], [disabledElevation], and
    /// [clipBehavior] arguments must not be null. Additionally,  [elevation],
    /// [highlightElevation], and [disabledElevation] must be non-negative.
    const RaisedButton({
    Key key,
    @required VoidCallback onPressed,
    ValueChanged<bool> onHighlightChanged,
    ButtonTextTheme textTheme,
    Color textColor,
    Color disabledTextColor,
    Color color,
    Color disabledColor,
    Color highlightColor,
    Color splashColor,
    Brightness colorBrightness,
    double elevation,
    double highlightElevation,
    double disabledElevation,
    EdgeInsetsGeometry padding,
    ShapeBorder shape,
    Clip clipBehavior = Clip.none,
    MaterialTapTargetSize materialTapTargetSize,
    Duration animationDuration,
    Widget child,
    }) : assert(elevation == null || elevation >= 0.0),
         assert(highlightElevation == null || highlightElevation >= 0.0),
         assert(disabledElevation == null || disabledElevation >= 0.0),
         super(
               key: key,
               onPressed: onPressed,
               onHighlightChanged: onHighlightChanged,
               textTheme: textTheme,
               textColor: textColor,
               disabledTextColor: disabledTextColor,
               color: color,
               disabledColor: disabledColor,
               highlightColor: highlightColor,
               splashColor: splashColor,
               colorBrightness: colorBrightness,
               elevation: elevation,
               highlightElevation: highlightElevation,
               disabledElevation: disabledElevation,
               padding: padding,
               shape: shape,
               clipBehavior: clipBehavior,
               materialTapTargetSize: materialTapTargetSize,
               animationDuration: animationDuration,
               child: child,
              );
   ```